# cache manifest update error over mobile network connection on Iphone standalone web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cache-manifest, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm creating a web app with asp.net . what I want is this app to be available offline with cache manifest and also to be on full screen(standalone) when is saved to home screen when used on smartphones. 
I use the code below to update the cache when there is a updated cache manifest available.

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e) {
        var r = confirm("A new version is available");
        if (r == true) {
            window.applicationCache.swapCache();
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }, false);
```

The problem now is , when I first open the homescreen app on iphone everything works fine and the update works perfect. But when I close the app and open it again if I use mobile networks(2g, 3g, lte) , update doesn't work at all , until I turn on Wi-Fi.

I red somewhere that this is some problem that mobile networks occur errors in javascript. But I didn't manage to solve the problem .